# How the layout adapt to content horizontally and vertically?

Tags: android, android-layout

is there any way to create a layout that wrap_content horizontally and if the line is full place the rest in new line(s).

example:

if I create a linear layout with orientation set to horizontal and then I create three buttons filling screen size(Button)(Button)(Button), now if I add more buttons it will be placed in a very ugly way in the end of the line. What I want is for the new buttons to be placed in new line, and I don't want to create more than one layout because these buttons are placed dynamically from java according to an API input. Is there anyway to do that, or I just have to design a function to handle it?

Comment: does the buttons have different width?? if not, will the 3 button always fill the width of the layout?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, but you can give me the idea if the buttons have the same width and I can adapt to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about `GridView`, Refer to [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

You should define grid view container in your_layout.xml

```
<your.package.ButtonsGridView
android:id="@+id/buttonsGridView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Then extends `GridView` to custom class named `ButtonsGridView`,

and then extends `ArrayAdapter<T>` to custom class named `ButtonsAdapter`, to manager data.

And set `ButtonsAdapter` to `ButtonsGridView`

```
ButtonsGridView buttonsGridView = (ButtonsGridView) findViewById(R.id.buttonsGridView);
ButtonsAdapter buttonsAdapter = new ButtonsAdapter(Context);
buttonsGridView.setAdapter(buttonsAdapter);
```

**In consideration of different button width**, you can manager width in adapter's method `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`, you can do anything you want to customize button.

Refer to this question&answer[Grid View change column number runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132832/how-does-grid-view-change-column-number-runtime) to change column number.

Comment: @YousifAl-Raheem my pleasure  (may be you could accept as your answer : )

Answer (score 1):

If your `View`s are dynamically added maybe you want to use a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) because it use an `Adapter` to obtain the `View`s that will be displayed on screen (same as `ListView`). But if you will add `View`s to the Layout in Design time, maybe you can use [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

Xamarin has a good explanation about `GridLayout` check it [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/gridlayout/)

Also you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307218/gridview-vs-gridlayout-in-android-apps) in SO to see a more detailed differences between the `GridView` and the `GridLayout`:

Answer (score 0):

Well if your button have different width size then you can use `GridView` where you set its `android:numColumns` as `auto_fit` where if first row is already filled with buttons then the next time you add a button will be added in the next line/row of the grid.

Lets say if you have a button with a width of `match_parent` then the next button added will be on the next line, hence if you have a **fixed** button width then it will add the button next to each other until it filled the gridview width and the next button that will be added will be on the next line.

If you want to implement the gridview then you can go [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).